# Samba share over File Managers (Dolphin)

Tags: linux, debian, samba, kde-plasma

I just switched from Kubuntu to Debian with KDE. In both I'm using Dolphin as file manager. But in Kubuntu I was able to do a simple samba share in the file/folder properties. I thought it would appear if I install samba, but that didn't happen. I started googling then, but I can't find a single hint with various search terms, so I hope someone here can give me a hint how to enable that.

EDIT: After a few Minutes more of googling I found out that I needed to install the pakage "**kdenetwork-filesharing**". 
Now I have the Share Tab, but the sharing don't work. Every Time I klick "OK" it didn't save it..